# C++ Server - Client Message Sync

Tags: c++

I writing a small program that can Send File from Client -> Server (Send) and Server -> Client(Request).

Well done this part but the problems comes when:
1. I found the File on Server, How can I execute a cin on the client side?
2. How can I force my messages between Server and Client to be synced? I mean I dont want the Server to move to next step or freeze on the receive.
For Example(No Threading applied in this porblem):-
Server: Waiting a Message from Client.
Client: Send the Message.
Client: Waiting a Message from Client.
Server: Send the Message.
.....etc.

In a rare times the messages arrive on order but 99.999% of the time they don't and the program on two sides freeze.

The problem with the inorder messages was a thread on the client side who kept reading the inc replies without allowing the actual functions to see them.

However, about point 1.
I am trying in this code:
1. No shared resources so i am trying to define everything inside this function (part of it where the problem happening) 
2. I was trying to pass this function to a thread so the server can accept more clients.
3. send & receive nothing special about them just a normal send/recv calls.
3. Question: if SendMyMessage & ReceiveMyMessage is going to be used by different threads, should I pass the socket to them with the message?

```
void ExecuteRequest(void * x)
{

RequestInfo * req = (RequestInfo *) x;
        // 1st Message Direction get or put
fstream myFile;          
myFile.open(req->_fName);


char tmp;
string _MSG= "";
string cFile = "*";
if(req->_fDir.compare("put") == 0)
{
    if(myFile.is_open())
    {
        SendMyMessage("*F*");
        cFile = ReceiveMyMessage(); 
// I want here to ask the client what to do after he found the that file exist on the server, 
// I want the client to to get a message "*F*", then a cin command appear to him
// then the client enter a char 
// then a message sent back to the server
// then the server continue executing the code

//More code         
}
```

Client side:

```
{
cout <<"Waiting Message" <<endl;
    temps = ReceiveMessage();

    if(temps.compare("*F*") == 0)
    {
        cout <<"File found on Server want to:\n(1)Replace it.\n(2)Append to it." <<endl;
        cin>>temps;
        SendMyMessage(temps);
    }}
```

I am using visual studio 2013 
Windowx 7
thread am using: _beginthread (I removed all threads)

Regards,

Comment: Maybe you didnt see the "Well done this part but the problems comes when". Only those 2 points I still trying to solve.

Comment: Ok, show the problematic part of your code. It's hard to say anything now.

Comment: k Thanks, I added the part of code dealing with this issue

Answer (score 0):

On linux, there is a system call "select" using which the server can wait on the open sockets. As soon as there is an activity, like client wrote something, the server wakes up on that sockets and processes the data.

You are on windows platform. So :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx